# 2 Thermostats one furnace

Tags: heating

Is there a way to have one zone at a time calling for heat? i have 2 zones an one furnace temp is house ok if one stat calls for heat but when they both it takes forever to heat house

Comment: Is this a forced-air system, or something else? How are you going to prevent the other zone from being heated when one zone is calling for heat?

Comment: Note that **if you set up some means to only have one zone at a time on, it will still take "forever" to heat the house,** as the other zone will be cooling below setpoint when it's calling for heat but not getting any, and vice versa. Sounds like your system is either undersized, or you are having temperatures near the design limit (when the furnace should be "just barely keeping up" if the system is designed correctly.) In most houses, particularly older ones, your quickest benefit will be from air-sealing & weatherstripping to reduce air leakage; next step - additional insulation.

Comment: my furnace is a energy kinetics system 2000 uses oil an i own a Duplex and I zone spliting the home so 2 zones And I have the old cast radiators water kind not steam home is well Insulated Because I re did it and put a new in

Comment: I'd check the air sealing at this point, using a blower door test + thermographs.  (Insulation doesn't help if there's hot air flying out a giant air leak.)  Other than that, I'd run Manual J and S calcs and check to make sure you have adequate radiation in the zones to use the boiler capacity up.

Comment: just to give u guys an update i checked in to what the one guy said about undersize furnace an thats what it is the new one that i just had installed is 90,000 btu/hr an in my area an size of home i need around 150,000 so thank u guys for helping i guess the sales man messed something up

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have one zone at a time calling for heat?

yes

maybe with a newer style boiler controller like a `hydrostat 3250` or definitely with a `zone control` such as `Taco SR503-4 Switching Relay`

at first thought you could wire one of the zones as the domestic hot water priority on the boiler controller provided it has a priority zone connection, which is typically where your boiler heats an indirect hot water tank (for your shower and all your faucets) in addition to heating zones... so whenever the device on the DHW priority calls for heat it gets priority and all the other heat zones if they were calling for heat have to wait for whatever is on that priority zone stops calling for heat.  You would just choose whichever zone of your two would be the priority, and if you have a domestic hot water indirect tank then put that on a different regular zone connection.

A zone control like the TACO I mentioned can do it

> Taco Switching Relays combine clearly labeled PC board layouts with advanced features that allow for total system customization. Whether using basic priority switching or the advanced features of the -EXP controls, the job is made easy

you can read hydrostat hydrolevel manual here to understand its capabilities: https://hydrolevel.com/fuel-smart-hydrostat-3200-plus3250-plus/